# Interchanging limits of integration for an even function

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, even-and-odd-functions

I wanted to know is this true for an even function $\mathbf f(x)$:

$\int_a^b$$\mathbf f(x)$ $\mathbf =$$\int_b^a$$\mathbf f(x)$

That is, there is no requirement of a negative sign while interchanging the limits of integration.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is *not* true, since, *by definition*, if $b<a$, then $\displaystyle\int_b^af(x)\,\mathrm dx=-\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$.

Answer (score 1):

No, as José Carlos Santos points out. But it is true that $$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=\int_{-b}^{-a}f(x)\,dx$$ for even functions